# Scala web framework performance on raspberry pi

Tags: scala, playframework, raspberry-pi, lift, scalatra

I need to write a small Web based UI that would run on a `raspi` and since I'm trying to pull some Scala into my daily work, I'd like to use one of `Play`, `Scalatra` or `Lift`. Does anybody have experience with developing for Raspberry Pi with these frameworks? If so, which one is more advisable in terms of performance?

Comment: Play, Lift, even Scalatra or, really, Scala at all are probably nearly impossible on such a device. In addition to flavian's point about RAM, Scala is arguably only viable on desktop, server or what would qualify today as high-end mobile devices from a CPU speed and processor cache standpoint.

Comment: @{flavian, Randall} :The pi B has 512 MB RAM, I wouldn't consider it a low memory environment. I've already used it with Scala and it works quite well actually,  my concerns are about overhead from these frameworks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

People have reported very good low memory performance using Scalatra. One example write-up is at:

http://fehguy.tumblr.com/post/33760322808/my-house-heater-has-a-rest-api-with-phidgets-scala

Memory usage figures as low as ~30MB to ~40MB have been bandied about in blog posts and IRC conversations.

Some tips:

1) Scalatra allows you to select exactly the dependencies you want. The core HTTP router will work just fine on a Raspberry Pi - be extremely careful with selecting additional libraries and benchmark your memory usage whenever you add a new jar.

2) The current Scalatra g8 template will, by default, wire up precompiled Scalate templates for you. These are fine on a normal server, and it's usually very convenient to have things set up for you already, but in a memory-constrained environment they are the first thing you'll want to look at either ditching or optimising.

3) At least three people in the #scalatra irc channel on Freenode have already experimented with running it on a Pi, so depending on your use cases(s) their pain may be your gain.

4) You'll get the best possible memory consumption by launching your Scalatra app as a standalone Jetty servlet. This is detailed in the [Scalatra standalone deployment guide](http://scalatra.org/2.2/guides/deployment/standalone.html).

Comment: I've actually made a first try with Play and although it needs around a minute to boot, it runs pretty good after that. If I run into any performance troubles, I'll consider Scalatra. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Diego Medina blogged a while back about successfully using Lift on a Raspberry Pi: http://blog.fmpwizard.com/blog/lift-running-on-raspberrypi.